Affixing Mezuzah without case or cover
In Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 289/1 the Mechaber writes:

בא לקבעה יניחנה בשפופרת של קנה או של כל דבר ויקבענה במקומה ויברך אקב"ו לקבוע מזוזה ולא יברך בשעת כתיבתה. (והקובע ב' או ג' מזוזות מברך ברכה אחת לכולן) (בית יוסף בשם תשובת הרשב"א):
One who is coming to affix [a mezuzah] should place it in a reed or other type of tube and he should affix it in its place and say the placing “who sanctified us with His commandments and commanded us to affix a mezuzah” and one should not make a blessing when the mezuzah is being written. Rema: One who is affixing two or three mezuzot should make one blessing for all of them.

The Pitchei teshuva brings the following:

יניחנה בשפופרת. בהנהגת החסיד הגר"א ז"ל כתב לא יכרוך המזוזה בקלף וכדומה שלא יהא חוצץ בין המזוזה למזוזות הבית עכ"ד וצ"ע

Loosely translated - in the minhagim of the Gaon of Vilna it is written not to wrap the Mezuza with a parchment so that there is no "Chatzitza" between the doorpost annd the Mezuaza.
Some questions that arise:

What are sources for such a minhag?
Do any contemproray Poskim bring this Le'Halacha?
How would one affix a Mezuza to the wall and how would it be kept safe from becoming Pasul quickly by rain etc.? (if edging a space into the doorpost is the only solution then how does the Gemara in Bava Metzia 102a say "בְּגוּבְתָּא דְּקַנְיָא
to insert a mezuza inside a hollow reed and then affix the whole arrangement to the doorpost")?


The reed is attached to the doorpost and is an extension of it. Parchment paper wrapping is not attached to the door and interrupts (on this view) between the scroll and the greater doorpost

https://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=12&rid=759 see the paragraph starting וכן נראה, which seems to be what Double AA is saying

@אילפא thanks for the great resource. Per that pshat the Gaon is OK with using a Reed,  but not ok with also wrapping the Mezuza in klaf in the Reed. I didn't interpret DoubleAA's answer to mean that, but it's great if he did. BTW, is this "even Yisrael" rav Fischer zatza"l?

@Yoreinu , yes this is Dayan Fischer.
